# Разбить txt файл на несколько html

Tags: c#, .net, html

Построчно читаю текстовый файл, обрабатываю эту строку (добавляю теги к некоторым словам) и записываю ее в html страницу. Есть переменная, которая задает количество строк в выходном HTML файле, например, 100, необходимо при достижении этого количества строк создавать новый html файл и т.д., пока не обработается весь текст, т.е. если в текстовом файле 250 строк, то в итоге должно получится 3 html файла: `out1.html`, `out2.html`, `out3.html`.
Пока получилось только так (в один html):

```
public void TextToHtml(string filepath)

      {
            var writer = new StreamWriter("output.html", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            writer.Write("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Text</title></head><body>");
            var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                string result_str = line;
                string[] spl = line.Split(new char[] {' '});

                foreach (var word in spl)
                {
                    string word_temp = word.Trim(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!' });
                    if (dict.Contains(word_temp))
                    {
                        var pattern = String.Format(@"(?i)\b{0}\b", word_temp);
                        var word_tag = String.Format(@"<b><i>{0}</i></b>",word_temp);
                        result_str = Regex.Replace(result_str, pattern, word_tag);

                    }

                }
                writer.Write(result_str+"<br>");
            }
            writer.Write("</body></html>");
            writer.Close();

        }
```

Как наиболее правильно переделать под задачу (чтобы формировалось несколько html, в зависимости от переменной)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема легко решается счётчиком, как отвечено выше, я лишь напишу алгоритм чуть поточнее:

```
var maxStr = 100;
var count = 0;

foreach(var line as lines){
  if(count > maxStr){
   // Понимаем что время пришло... поменять файл!
   count = 0; // Обнуляем счётчик
  }
  // Тут обрабатываем строку
  count++; // Инкрементируем счётчик
}
```

Всё гениальное - просто!

Answer (score 1):

Завести счетчик и от него отталкиваться.

```
var tmp_count = 0;
var max_count_line = 100;

if(tmp_count > max_count_line)
{
  // пишем в новый файл
  tmp_count = 0;
}
tmp_count++;
```

Comment: Это понятно, но если вы посмотрите? там цикл foreach, проблематично туда вставить такую конструкцию